Time complexity of Reconstruct Itinerary
This is a question that almost all resources I encountered, leetcode editorial and such, claim a time complexity of $O(E^d)$; and in the comment sections of almost all of them, people, like myself, are questioning if this should be $O(d^E)$. No one seems to be responding. I smell some trick of some sort here, that few realize, that makes $O(E^d)$ valid. Any ideas?
Question:

You are given a list of airline tickets where tickets[i] = [fromi, toi] represent the departure and the arrival airports of one flight. Reconstruct the itinerary in order and return it.


All of the tickets belong to a man who departs from "JFK", thus, the itinerary must begin with "JFK". If there are multiple valid itineraries, you should return the itinerary that has the smallest lexical order when read as a single string.


For example, the itinerary ["JFK", "LGA"] has a smaller lexical order than ["JFK", "LGB"].
You may assume all tickets form at least one valid itinerary. You must use all the tickets once and only once.



Input: tickets = [["MUC","LHR"],["JFK","MUC"],["SFO","SJC"],["LHR","SFO"]]


Output: ["JFK","MUC","LHR","SFO","SJC"]



Input: tickets = [["JFK","SFO"],["JFK","ATL"],["SFO","ATL"],["ATL","JFK"],["ATL","SFO"]]


Output: ["JFK","ATL","JFK","SFO","ATL","SFO"]


Explanation: Another possible reconstruction is ["JFK","SFO","ATL","JFK","ATL","SFO"] but it is larger in lexical order.

Solution:
class Solution:
    def findItinerary(self, tickets: List[List[str]]) -> List[str]:
        adj = {src: [] for src, dst in tickets}
        res = []

        for src, dst in tickets:
            adj[src].append(dst)

        for key in adj:
            adj[key].sort()

        def dfs(adj, result, src):
            if src in adj:
                destinations = adj[src][:]
                while destinations:
                    dest = destinations[0]
                    adj[src].pop(0)
                    dfs(adj, res, dest)
                    destinations = adj[src][:]
            res.append(src)

        dfs(adj, res, "JFK")
        res.reverse()

        if len(res) != len(tickets) + 1:
            return []

        return res

